# FizzBuzz returning empty array

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I'm not quite sure why this is returning an empty array, does anyone have any clues or hints? Any help is appreciated.

```js
function fizzBuzz() {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      array.push("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      array.push("Buzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      array.push("FizzBuzz");
    }
    return array;
  }
}
fizzBuzz();
```

Comment: Your `return` is inside the `for` loop, meaning it will return right after the first iteration.

Comment: Because you return the array in the first iteration.

Comment: Because ur returning the array at the bottom of the for loop when `i` is still 1. Move the return outside the next bracket.

Comment: @chiliNUT Do try and use full words like "your" as things like "ur" can confuse non-native English speakers and translation tools that many people depend on for understanding.

Comment: @tadman But it's so kewl!

Comment: wow, very silly mistake. thanks for the fresh eyes!

Comment: There's another mistake here you're about to discover. Hint: Under what circumstances will the third clause run?

Answer (score 2):

You return from inside the loop after the first iteration.

```
function fizzBuzz() {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      array.push("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      array.push("Buzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      array.push("FizzBuzz");
    }
  }
  return array; // <- !
}
fizzBuzz();
```

Answer (score 1):

**First issue**, The return statement is inside the loop. It will return an empty array after the first iteration. Place the return statement after the loop instead.

**Second issue**, You need to check the FizzBuzz in the first if statement else it won't ever hit

```
function fizzBuzz() {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      array.push("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      array.push("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      array.push("Buzz");
    }
  }
  return array;
}
fizzBuzz();
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Makes sense!

Comment: Sorry, since I'm new to SO the vote is recorded but not seen!